# How to explicitly use Jackson ObjectMapper setSerializationInclusion on different sub class?

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jsonserializer

I have a nested class object that I would like to apply `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL` and `JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS` on its child class, I don't have access to directly add the Annotation on my child class so I have to configure a way in ObjectMapper that could help me when deserialize the response

```
public class MyParentClass {
   public MyNonNullClass myNonNullClass;
   public MyAlwaysClass myAlwaysClass;
} 
// would like to perform as Annotation @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class MyNonNullClass {}
// would like to perform as Annotation @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.ALWAYS)
public class MyNonNullClass {}
```

When I register my ObjectMapper I use `setSerializationInclusion` but it would apply same Inclusion to both of my child classes

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.disable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
om.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
// om.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS);
om.registerSubtypes(MyNonNullClass.class, MyAlwaysClass.class);
```

Is there anyway to customized ObjectMapper that so I can apply differently on different sub class/types?